Display callkit not show after outgoing callkeep in IOS
const startCall = () => {
    const uuid = '95f1ed69-9d64-45e9-9d03-ba4153f4fd03';
    const handle = '1234567890';
    RNCallKeep.startCall(uuid, handle, 'Caller', 'generic', false);
};

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"newProject";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  
  [RNCallKeep setup:@{
        @"appName": @"newProject",
        @"maximumCallGroups": @3,
        @"maximumCallsPerCallGroup": @1,
        @"supportsVideo": @YES,
   }];

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(startCall:(NSString *)uuidString
                  handle:(NSString *)handle
                  contactIdentifier:(NSString * _Nullable)contactIdentifier
                  handleType:(NSString *)handleType
                  video:(BOOL)video)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"[RNCallKeep][startCall] uuidString = %@", uuidString);
#endif
    int _handleType = [RNCallKeep getHandleType:handleType];
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];
    CXHandle *callHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:_handleType value:handle];
    CXStartCallAction *startCallAction = [[CXStartCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:uuid handle:callHandle];
    [startCallAction setVideo:video];
    [startCallAction setContactIdentifier:contactIdentifier];

    CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:startCallAction];

    [self requestTransaction:transaction];
}

[RNCallKeep][requestTransaction] transaction = <CXTransaction 0x281110b60 UUID=5626BEF4-A00D-4C31-8E1D-2A94E4EC6D09 isComplete=0 actions=(
    "<CXStartCallAction 0x282339950 UUID=793349CD-7979-4FEC-828E-567135E04403 state=0 commitDate=(null) callUUID=95f1ed69-9d64-45e9-9d03-ba4153f4fd03 handle=<CXHandle 0x2811109a0 type=Generic value=1234567890> contactIdentifier=Caller video=0 relay=0 upgrade=0 retry=0 emergency=0 isVoicemail=0 ttyType=0 localLandscapeAspectRatio={0, 0} localPortraitAspectRatio={0, 0} dateStarted=(null) localSenderIdentityUUID=(null) shouldSuppressInCallUI=0>"
)>

there is no call details screen displayed. Instead, I only see the status bar indicating that there’s an ongoing call, but I can’t navigate to the phone screen. I’m wondering if I missed something during the setup or if I need to use any additional functions.
I would like to see the callkit screen after starting a call from callkeep to show the user that the call is in an outgoing call.
